# Share Windows PPPOE connection with Linux

Tags: linux, windows, networking, internet, raspberry-pi

I have a windows computer connected wirelessly to router and connected to Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Linux) with LAN cable. I need to connect to PPPOE connection and enter my credentials to connect to internet with windows computer and that works fine. But I need to connect to Raspberry Pi to internet  through my Windows computer internet connection. I followed some tutorials but can't manage this to work.

1) I set static IP on my windows computer ethernet connection (192.168.0.1)

2) I shared my PPPOE connection on windows computer

3) I edited /etc/network/interfaces to look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
dns-search 192.168.0.1
```

And I can't get internet connection on Raspberry Pi. I can ping my windows computer from raspberry and other other way round but i cant ping google.com or open any internet site... What am I missing?

Comment: Can your router handle the PPPoE connection?

Comment: No, i must dial it from computer.

Comment: I suggest either 1) Buying a new router that can negotiate a PPPoE connection. or 2) Installing an alternate firmware, like DD-WRT, on your current router that can negotiate a PPPoE connection.

Comment: The router is locked by ISP so I can't change it. I must admit that I had this working some time ago, so it is possible, but now it just doesn't work... Maybe some necessary Windows serivces are stopped? What services are needed for sharing internet? I just can't figure out what has changed since last time I was connecting raspberry to internet...

Comment: Does anyone have some other suggestion for setting some windows/linux options rather than changing the router?